# boot-repair error message meaning, and assistance on next step

Tags: 14.04, uefi, windows-8, bios, boot-repair

Please help me understand what this means, also what is the next step to recovering my initial operating system Win 8 ?

I've been wrestling with this for so long. For crying-out-loud they now have Windows 10..

Will you please help me figure out how to run alongside Linux and Ubuntu via software ... not CD or USB. I just want to switch the OS manually with software.

Thank you,

Aksana J. Buster

[screen-shot of an error message I got when attempting to recover Win8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4dQR.png**)

Comment: `how to run alongside Linux and Ubuntu via software`
Please be clear , do you want to run Ubuntu as a virtual machine ? , if yes what's your host (main ) OS is it a Microsoft product or Linux ?

Comment: I bought this at a Windows 8 computer then got a CD with linux then "Ran alongside windows and linux".

Answer (score 0):

You can't install an operating system via "software". You have to use a DVD or USB drive for that. Boot-repair tells you to boot using UEFI mode - this is set in UEFI by going into boot options and selecting the usb drive with UEFI prefix. You can set up a virtual machine in Windows for Linux, if that is what you mean to want.

Comment: Thank you for helping! I think it's already installed now.. I just can't seem to access my Win8 OS. 

So you're saying when i get to the boot menu, i will see and option that says UEFI mode, and click on it? Or what's the next step when I get there? 

Thank you,

Aksana J. Buster

Comment: Before you turn on  the computer, insert the USB drive with Ubuntu. Then just when you turn on the computer and see the initial screen, you should be able to press Delete or F2 (depends on motherboard) and that will bring you to UEFI. There should be a menu. You have to find Boot settings where you should be able to set the order of drive booting. Set your USB drive with "UEFI" option as first. Also, "Secure boot" must be disabled. Then when you save and exit, the computer will boot ubuntu in UEFI mode. Then you can try running Boot-repair again.

Comment: Will this allow me to run Ubuntu and Windows 8 alongside eachother? I have ubuntu on a CD too by the ways.

Comment: Yes, if the boot-repair will work. What instructions did you follow to recover Windows? Give the link, if possible.

Comment: Picture of START UP:    https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/110169447915426001075/album/6277978384828244161/6277978388199412514?authkey=CKuAuoLinv663AE

BOOT MENU:     https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/110169447915426001075/album/6277978384828244161/6277978385960480962?authkey=CKuAuoLinv663AE